# Collections.sort with anonymous Comparable is giving an error

Tags: java, collections

first of all I have to say that I did extensively search for an answer to this, but I was unable to found it.

Basically I use the exact same format as tons of other sites use, but my NetBeans is giving an error to this.

My code:

```
package ocr;

public class Property {    
    public static final int METHOD_NORMAL_SEARCH = 1;
    public static final int METHOD_ADVANCED_SEARCH = 2;

    private String property;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    protected HashMap<String, Integer> values;

    public Property(String propertyName, ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.property = propertyName;
        this.names = new ArrayList<>();
        this.values = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : names) {
            this.names.add(s);
        }
    }

    public void add(String value, int method) {
        values.put(value, method);
    }

    public int calculateSimilarity(String value) {
        if (names.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("names cannot be empty.");
        }
        LevenshteinDistance ld = new LevenshteinDistance();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String n : names) {
            list.add(ld.calculate(value, n));
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list.get(0);
    }

    public void search(File input) {
        HashMap<String, Values> table = new HashMap<>();    //Maps word to {similarity, location in file}
        CustomScanner scanner = new CustomScanner(input);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String next = scanner.next();
            table.put(next, new Values(calculateSimilarity(next), scanner.getPosition()));
        }

        //Sorting on similarity
        Collections.sort(table, new Comparator<Values>() {
            @Override public int compare(Values val1, Values val2) {
                return Integer.signum(val1.similarity - val2.similarity);
            }
        });
    }

    public void advancedSearch(File input) {

    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("--" + property + "--");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : values.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + entry.getKey() + " / Method: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private class Values {
        private int similarity;
        private int position;

        public Values(Integer similarity, Integer position) {
            this.similarity = similarity;
            this.position = position;
        }

        public int getSimilarity() {
            return similarity;
        }

        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

The error which I got:

```
C:\Users\Frank\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OCR\src\ocr\Property.java:62: error: no suitable method found for sort(HashMap<String,Property.Values>,<anonymous Comparator<Property.Values>>)
        Collections.sort(table, new Comparator<Values>() {
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#1 exist so that argument type HashMap<String,Property.Values> conforms to formal parameter type List<T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>)
1 error
```

All other advice is obviously welcome aswell.

I am either really not noticing some obvious mistake, or there might be some harder issue going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collection.sort` doesn't apply for a `Map` The [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) function just receives a `List` and `Map` doesn't implement this interface. If you need to have your `Map` items sorted, consider using a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Is it possible to give me a bit more of an insight in how to make it a TreeMap, simply changing HashMap to TreeMap might have been a too easy way of thinking.

Also, how would you guys (the people answering me), solve a problem like this?

You have a table of:
Key(String) - Value1(Integer) - Value2(Integer)

And you want it to be sorted on Value1, while obviously preserving the relation between Key-Value1-Value2.

Any help on this would be appreciated a lot aswell.

Comment: Sorry it is annoying to use edits, but I cannot respond to my own question yet: Sidenote: Is it strange that I couldn't find out myself that you cannot sort a HashMap? I mean neither the error, nor NetBeans nor google results led me to believe that that could be the issue.

Comment: Last edit: I just changed HashMap<String, Values> where Values is of form {Integer, Integer} to ArrayList<Values> where Values is of form {String, Integer, Integer} this seems to be working well. Thank you all of your answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can't sort a HashMap. It makes no sense. A List can be sorted. An array can be sorted. But not a HashMap.